# How to use OAuth in triggered Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, blogger

I have been able to run a Google apps script with [this](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) OAuth2 library.
I have collected the 'authorization url' in Logger, copied and pasted it in a new tab and gained access. Finally, I used the blogger API to perform some tasks.

My question is can I do this process automatically? What I mean is I want to add a trigger and want the script to run everyday and perform some tasks in Blogger, something like take my daily inputs from Spreadsheet and post it in Blogger.

In the past, I did the same task through the MailApp. I am curious if that can be done through Blogger API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I do it? I have learned OAuth only a bit. I don't know to get the access token again and again automatically.

Comment: How are you getting access token now?

Comment: `var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
Logger.log(authorizationUrl);`  @TheMaster Edit: Ah, sorry. this is the url.

Comment: That should be done only once. Refresh token is stored and the library automatically authenticates next time you run the script.

Comment: So, I need to store the token for the next run?

Comment: it's automatically stored when you authorize. In any case, You don't need to use oauth library as said in the duplicate question below. Also, when asking questions, provide [mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster I have checked that link, and used that code. I have two questions. 1. Should I still generate credentials? 2. Should I still use the OAuth Library? I used the library. I am getting an error like this -    "message": "Blogger API v3 has not been used in project 31005190412 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/blogger.googleapis.com/overview?project=31005190412 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.", .Also the link gives an error.

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. You still need to enable the api after switching to standard GCP. Read the links and the comments in the duplicate question

Comment: It worked. Thanks @TheMaster I was not associating the script with the project earlier. It is working beautifully now. :)

Comment: @TheMaster An extension to the question. What should be the general approach to do the same thing for other APIs i.e other than Google services?

Comment: Use the oauth library.